# How to call script based on value of Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code that is used when logging in and it works.  However, if the login successful, I need to close the form.  I have a button that does that which the user can click, but I don't know how to wire that up so I can call it programmatically.  The Model has a property called IsAuthenticated.  So if that is true, then I need to call the cancelLogin() function which will close the window.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "loginSection", }))
    {
        @Html.Partial("_LoginInfoPartial", Model) 
        <input} type="submit" value="Log in" />
        <button type="button"  id="close_button" onclick="cancelLogin()" >Cancel</button>

        <script>
            function cancelLogin()
            {
                var window = $("#loginWindow").data("kendoWindow");
                window.close();
            } 
        </script>
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within your controller on a successful login, you could return a call to that function. For example:

```
public ActionResult Login() {
    // login logic here

    if(loginSuccess)
        return Content("<script>cancelLogin();</script>");
    else
        return View();
}
```

So when the form loads from the backend, it will replace your `div` with this Javascript which should execute and close the window.